# Google Sheets App Script Html onload not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google sheets and I'm creating a document that will pull through employees that are out of the office. I have a menu option to remove employee data, and it opens the sidebar where I have an HTML form ([Image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CRwB.png)). I'm trying to have it generate a dropdown list of current employees on the list.

I've developed the code to pull through the data I need:

```js
function removeAnyone() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('RemoveAnyone');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}

function getList() {
  var headerRows = 1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows + 1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - headerRows, 1);
  var arrayValues = range.getValues();
  return arrayValues;
}
```

Now we move over to my html, where I am simply trying to load the dropdown list using a for loop in the header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function addOption_list() {

     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "test";

    var options = google.script.run.getList();

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i;) {
      var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
      optn.text = options[i];
      optn.value = options[i];
      document.myForm.selectEmployee.options.add(optn);

      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="addOption_list()">
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="submitForm(this)">
    <select id="selectEmployee">
      <option>Choose an employee</option>
     </select>
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I threw a div in the body and have the function changing the value to "test" at the start, this was just to check and see if the function was even being called, which it doesn't seem like it is.

I also tried using window.onload (as shown below), but that didn't get me anywhere either.:

```js
window.onload = function {

     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "test";

    var options = google.script.run.getList();

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i;) {
      var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
      optn.text = options[i];
      optn.value = options[i];
      document.myForm.selectEmployee.options.add(optn);

      }
    }
```

Any guidance you can give me would be really appreciated!

Comment: Stack snippets should be used only for executable JavaScript/HTML/CSS. Google Apps Script isn't executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`google.script.run` doesn't return values. When you want to return values from GAS, please use `withSuccessHandler`. And the data retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. So how about this modification?

### Modified script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addOption_list).getList();
    }
    function addOption_list(options) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "test";
      var select = document.getElementById('selectEmployee');
      for ( var i in options) {
        var optn = document.createElement('option');
        optn.value = options[i][0];
        optn.text = options[i][0];
        select.appendChild(optn);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="submitForm(this)">
    <select id="selectEmployee">
      <option>Choose an employee</option>
     </select>
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Reference :

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: That worked amazing! Thank you so much. I also noticed that I left out the getElementByID in my original post, which I did have before I started trying to clean up the garbage so I could post it haha.

Comment: Anyways, I do have a follow up question. Do you know why it comes through as a 2 dimensional array? I would have loved just a regular array. My best guess is that ranges are always two dimensional, just in case. But possibly it was a mistake in my .gs file?

Comment: @Anthony Bahl ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addOption_list).getList()`` means that at first, ``getList()`` of GAS is run, and when ``getList()`` was completely run, ``addOption_list()`` of RemoveAnyone.html is run by ``withSuccessHandler(addOption_list)``. At this time, at ``getList()`` in your script, ``range.getValues();`` is returned. This value is sent to ``addOption_list()``. In my modified script, the value is given to ``options`` by ``addOption_list(options)``. By this, it was found that ``options`` is 2 dimensional array. Is my understanding of your comment correct?